# R Subset data.frame from max value of one vector and grouped by another

Tags: r, subset

```
>ID<-c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C')
>WK<-c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>NumSuccess<-c(0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3)
>Data<-data.frame(ID, WK, NumSuccess)
```

I am trying to create a subset data.frame "Data2" based on the value in "NumSuccesses" that corresponds to the Max Value in "WK" grouped by "ID". Resulting data.frame should look like this:

```
>ID<-c('A','B','C')
>WK<-c(3, 3, 5)
>NumSuccess<-c(2, 1, 3)
>Data2<-data.frame(ID, WK, NumSuccess)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could be done in more than one way.  If there are ties for 'WK', maximum value per each 'ID' and want all the rows with the maximum 'WK', it may be useful to `filter` with the logical condition (`WK==max(WK)`) after grouping by the 'ID'.

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>% 
      filter(WK==max(WK))
#   ID WK NumSuccess
#1  A  3          2
#2  B  3          1
#3  C  5          3
```

If there is a single 'max' value for 'WK' per 'ID', we can use `which.max` or use `arrange` to order the dataset by 'WK' for each 'ID'

```
  Data %>% 
       group_by(ID) %>%
       slice(which.max(WK))
  #     ID WK NumSuccess
  #1  A  3          2
  #2  B  3          1
  #3  C  5          3

 Data %>%
       group_by(ID) %>%
       arrange(-WK) %>% 
       slice(1)
```

Similar approaches in `data.table` are

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Data)[, .SD[max(WK)==WK], ID]
setDT(Data)[, .SD[which.max(WK)], ID]
setkey(setDT(Data), WK)[, .SD[.N], ID]
```

Or we can use `ave` from `base R`

```
 Data[with(Data, ave(WK, ID, FUN=max)==WK),]
```

Comment: @user3594490  No problem.  Glad that it works for you