# Indexing data frames without data frame variable assignment?

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

For example, with a function that returns a data frame like `aggregate`, you can do this:

`aggregate(data, subset, mean)[, "row"]`

And you can access the columns of the rows this way.

How would you access specific data points, without doing something like this?

```
df <- aggregate(data, ....)
df[df$column == max(df$column), df$row] # returns row w/ max column value
```

There seems to be no way to do this without having the name of the data frame to reference.

Attempting something like this doesn't seem to work:

```
aggregate(data, subset, mean)[aggregate(data, subset, mean)$column == 
max(aggregate(data, subset,mean), "row"]
```

and it's also pretty ugly code so I'd rather not even if I could.

Comment: technically you could maybe try `within()`, but i didnt really get why you want to do that,...

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. At first line `df` is a function, not a variable that could be subsetable

Comment: Oh, sorry. That's definitely confusing.

Comment: @BigDataScientist How would you use `within()` for this context? Wouldn't that require deleting most of the data since it returns the modified data frame?

Comment: @BigDataScientist Also seems like you still wouldn't be able to make a comparison like `df$column == max(df$column)` without having the data frame assigned to reference

Comment: Side note: though I'm guilty as well (specifically `df`), using R function names as variables makes it both confusing to readers as well as problematic if you do not sufficiently define all necessary variables. For instance, if you forget to define `data`, then `aggregate(data, ...)` may eventually give you `Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`, because in that instance `data` is a *function* (of length 1, so you'll also get complaints about `arguments must have same length`). This comment quickly infringes on personal naming preferences, so is just a technique/suggestion.

Comment: (That was more an expansion of @gonzalez.ivan90's comment.)

Comment: you didnt answer my remark, but i guess in the end this answers yourquestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586382/r-subset-data-frame-from-max-value-of-one-vector-and-grouped-by-another